# What does :%S do in vim?

Tags: vim

As I tried to globally replace FOO with BAR in a vim buffer, I accidentally typed

```
:%S/FOO/BAR/
```

Note the uppercase `S` instead of the more suitable `s`.

Of course, it wouldn't replace my FOOs. That's understandable. Yet, vim split the window into two windows, both holding the same buffer.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find any `:help` on this behaviour. So, can someone explain what the uppercase `:%S` is supposed to do and where I can find help on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
:h :S
```

---

```
:[N]Sexplore[!] [dir]... Split&Explore current file's directory *:Sexplore*
```

Comment: Oh, stupid me... I tried `:help :S` but it didn't occur to me that `:S` was an abbreviation for `Sexplore`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It was nice to [re]discover this set of commands. I never actually used them, but they might have come in handy. :)

Comment: wtf? Why is the name of that command Sexplore, it sounds like something that happens in the bedroom....

Comment: @Wertilq, no reason it can't happen in the bedroom. But, really, the "S" stands for "split".